# Disable highlighted area while using Bootstrap Tour

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-tour

Good day!

I just started using Bootstrap Tour on our project and I seem to like it because of its simple yet functional interface. But I just have one tiny issue - how do I get the elements being highlighted by the tour to be temporarily disabled?

For example, if the current highlight of the tour is on a set of buttons, is there a way so that the users will not be able to click them while on tour?

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify callback functions when a step is shown/hidden. In those functions, you've acces to the current element, and you can act on it (see the documentation : [Tour Options](http://bootstraptour.com/#options)) :

```
var tour = new Tour({
    onShown: function(tour) {
        var step = tour._steps[tour._current];
        $(step.element).attr('disabled', true);
    },
    onHidden: function(tour) {
        var step = tour._steps[tour._current];
        $(step.element).removeAttr('disabled');
    }
})
```

Comment: FYI, the API has since been updated and you now need to use tour._options.steps[tour._current];

Answer (score 4):

For me, the easiest way to accomplish this was using CSS.

You can apply CSS to your highligthed element:

```
.tour-NameOfYourTour-element {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

This doesn't change anything visually, and clic don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Using the same callback technique, I decided to overlay a div instead of add the disabled attribute to the step element. **This works well when the backdrop is turned on and the element is not an input field** (i.e. the disabled property takes no effect).

First the css for the overlay:

```
.tour-step-backdrop-parent {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1100;
}
```

And the code (updated to account for backdrop padding and absolute positioned step element):

```
onShown: function(tour) {
    var step = tour._options.steps[tour._current];

    /// Overlay a div on the tour contents to prevent clicking
    // Remove any existing overlay divs - accounting for shown event being called on window resize
    $(step.element).siblings('.tour-step-backdrop-parent').remove();
    // Create overlay div
    var disabledOverlay = $('<div class="tour-step-backdrop-parent"></div>');
    // Insert overlay div before step element in DOM
    $(step.element).before(disabledOverlay);
    // Account for step's backdrop padding if any (double it since it surrounds the element)
    var padding = (step.backdropPadding || 0) * 2;
    // Set size of the overlay div to the step element's size and account for rounding by adding 1 pixel
    disabledOverlay.outerHeight(stepElement.outerHeight() + padding + 1).outerWidth(stepElement.outerWidth() + padding + 1);
    // Set position based on element's position and adjust for backdrop padding
    var offset = stepElement.offset();console.log(offset);
    offset.top = offset.top - (step.backdropPadding || 0);
    offset.left = offset.left - (step.backdropPadding || 0);
    disabledOverlay.offset(offset);
},
onHidden: function(tour) {
    var step = tour._options.steps[tour._current];
    // Remove overlay div
    $(step.element).siblings('.tour-step-backdrop-parent').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The API is updated, in [v0.12.0](https://github.com/sorich87/bootstrap-tour/releases/tag/v0.12.0) you can achieve the same functionality through the following code.

```
var tour = new Tour({
    onShown: function(tour) {
        var step = tour.getStep(tour._current);
        $(step.element).attr('disabled', true);
    },
    onHidden: function(tour) {
        var step = tour.getStep(tour._current);
        $(step.element).removeAttr('disabled');
    }
})
```

Credit goes to @zessx